# Common Friends Indicator

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables

- 1:) USER - contain user information {id,name,adress....etc}
- 2:) Relation - contains relation between my user
  {sender,acceptor,action}

Now when user "xyz" visits user "abc" 
 Abc's friends list should classify there mutual friends and only friends with abc..

---

> TABLE STRUCTURE OF "USER":
>   Column (id,user) values (1,xyz) (2,abc) , (3,lmn), (4,kmp)
>
> TABLE STRUCTURE OF Relation:
>   Column (sender,acceptor,action) values (1,2,1), (1,3,1) (2,3,1) (2,4,1)

values (1,2,1) in Relation mean that users 1 and 2 are friends?
action 1 represent that there are friends

> i want a view that has "all mutual friends" and "all friends of abc that are not mutual friends"

i hope i made my point any help appreciated

Comment: We need more info on the table structure and there relations? Or you can add the sample data and expected output ?

Comment: EXISTS, join group by having etc, several solutions possible.

Comment: @jarlh : can you write a sample query or share some link which may help i tired everything

Comment: @CoderofCode i am sorry will this be enought?

Comment: Will values (1,2,1) in Relation mean that users 1 and 2 are friends? Do you want a view that has "all mutual friends" and "all friends of abc that are not mutual friends"?

Comment: @SimoKivistö  YES exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends of user xyz are:

```
select sender from relation where acceptor = (select id from user where user = 'xyz')
union
select acceptor from relation where sender = (select id from user where user = 'xyz');
```

You can get them also by querying the tables just once:

```
select distinct case when r.sender = u.id then r.acceptor else r.sender end
from user u
join relation r on u.id in (r.sender, r.acceptor)
where u.user = 'xyz';
```

Now using one of above queries we can get abc's friends as well as xyz's friends. And by outer-joining xyz's friends to abc's friends, we can determine whether a friend of abc's is a mutual friend or not.

```
select 
  friends_of_abc.friend,
  friends_of_xyz.friend is not null as is_a_mutual_friend
from
(
  select distinct case when r.sender = u.id then r.acceptor else r.sender end as friend
  from user u
  join relation r on u.id in (r.sender, r.acceptor)
  where u.user = 'abc'
) friends_of_abc
left join
(
  select distinct case when r.sender = u.id then r.acceptor else r.sender end as friend
  from user u
  join relation r on u.id in (r.sender, r.acceptor)
  where u.user = 'xyz'
) friends_of_xyz on friends_of_xyz.friend = friends_of_abc.friend;
```

Comment: how to fetch other data from user table such as user address in this same view

Comment: Extend your friends_of_abc query: `... as friend, address from user u ...` and then use the column in your select clause: `select friends_of_abc.friend, friends_of_abc.address, ...`.

Comment: Ah, of course, that was stupid. Sorry. Add `join user frienduser on frienduser.id = friends_of_abc.friend` before the left join or at the end of the query and then add `, frienduser.address` to your select clause.